# PHP Merge Array and keep key

Tags: php, arrays, merge

i want to join two arrays where 1 key should join them.

```
    array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "MONAT" => "AUG"
        "MAIL_CNT" => "2"
      ]
     1 => array:2 [
        "MONAT" => "JUL"
        "MAIL_CNT" => "1"
      ]
    ]

    array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "MONAT" => "AUG"
        "ORDER_CNT" => "18"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "MONAT" => "JUL"
        "ORDER_CNT" => "1"
      ]
    ]
```

The result should be something like

```
array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "MONAT" => "AUG"
        "MAIL_CNT" => "2"
        "ORDER_CNT" => "18"
      ]
     1 => array:2 [
        "MONAT" => "JUL"
        "MAIL_CNT" => "1"
        "ORDER_CNT" => "1"
      ]
    ]
```

I cant figure out what to do.

Thanks in advance and greetings !

Comment: should your key MONAT match for both ? ts that the condition ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-replace-recursive.php)

```
$array = array_replace_recursive($a1, $a2);
```

Comment: convincing but if the condition is month have to match and array length doesn't match both array then it will fail

Comment: Works like a charm! I feel a bit ashamed, i just tried array_replace :-)

Answer (score 1):

you should use php `array_replace_recursive()` for this

```
$arr1=array(
    0 =>array(
        "MONAT" => "AUG",
        "MAIL_CNT" => "2"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "MONAT" => "JUL",
        "MAIL_CNT" => "1"
    )
);

$arr2=array(
    0 => array(
        "MONAT" => "AUG",
        "ORDER_CNT" => "18"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "MONAT" => "JUL",
        "ORDER_CNT" => "1"
    )
);

$array = array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
echo"<pre>"; print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mergedArray = array();
foreach( $arr1 as $key => $row) {
    $mergedArray[$key] = array_merge($arr2[$key], $row)
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: While this method doesn't have a lot of moving parts to talk about, it is important to try to provide some explanation with answers and avoid code-only posts so that future SO readers are educated.

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** simple use `array_merge`

**2nd :** `&` means it is passed by reference instead of `value`

```
foreach( $array1 as $key => &$val) {
   $val = array_merge($val,$array2[$key]);
}
print_r($array1);
```

**Note :** Above code will work only if `both array count` is same otherwise it will throw the error .